Unable to create fields in scratch org with namespace, winter 25
I have an ongoing app development, with a namespace.
I need to use some new features like lightning/uiListsApi so I created a scratch org with api version 62 / Winter 25 release.
When trying to push my code, which works perfectly on my v.61 scratch, I get a lot of errors related to missing metadata like fields.
For fields the error is

An unexpected error occurred. Please include this ErrorId if you contact support: 1421273770-9991 (1336060917)`.

So I decided to create an object and a field in the UI, retrieve it, and upload it again, in case the meta.xml format would have changed.
The object creation was ok but it's impossible to create the field, still in th UI, I get

Cannot Modify Managed Component
The component you are attempting to modify is part of a managed package, and cannot be modified. For more information, see Insufficient Privileges Errors.

sf org display -o myScratchName shows that the namespace is the one configured in my sfdx-project.json, which is also the one added to the created SObject developername.
I don't like to call issues bugs before all other possibilities are out but I don't know what to do, is that a bug in v 62 ? did anyone meet the same issue ?
And know how to fix it ?
Thanks.

Tried again today, push worked.... I changed nothing, maybe Salesforce has patched a bug...
